# Beginner looking to get critique on my code so I can learn better

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

I am learning python and am a beginner. I am looking for some critique, advice, better ways to do things on my code so I can continue to improve with my coding skills.

the prompt: *It’s...not really an adventure game...*

> Ver 1.0
>
> Your village is being attacked by 'a germanic tribe' and you need to run to the stores and get the right things to save your village, and probably some good looking girl or boy you want to marry. All prices in gold pieces excl. VAT... chop chop!! ze germanz are coming! The code should allow you to get 1 thing from each store and each item you get should be removed from the store inventory, then do same for next store... one way to buy by typing the key 'newt' in an input box...or something at end you should print the 'items' you have taken..in this version you don't have to pay for stuff or add it up

> ver 1.2
>
> add ability to exit a store without buying and go to next by typing 'exit', and to exit if a nonexistant item is bought(typed) Add purse with 1000 gold pieces and payment for the items during or at end of code and show a message about total cost and how much gold you have left

> ver 1.4
>
> random bug fix, ' browser compatability', refactoring code... basically being lazy ..stop scrolling TikTok/Facebook! ;-)

> Ver 1.5
>
> print inventory before and after purchases as one department_store of stuff(combine inventories from all stores into one...pretend Big Biz bought all the local stores, and want constant reporting for inventory management...) as in all games there is a special way to do this that actually makes money and solves the problem...can you find 'them'? Do you know why? May require knowledge of actual python 'lore'

I am positive there are better, faster ways to write this code. But I tried doing this without looking for answers or getting help to test where I am with my knowledge. Looking for more experienced coders to help guide me.

thanks in advance.

```
freelancers = {'name': 'freelancing Shop','brian': 70, 'black knight': 20, 'biccus diccus': 100, 'grim reaper': 500, 'minstrel': -15}
antiques = {'name': 'Antique Shop','french castle': 400, 'wooden grail': 3, 'scythe': 150, 'catapult': 75, 'german joke': 5}
pet_shop = {'name': 'Pet Shop','blue parrot': 10, 'white rabbit': 5, 'newt': 2}

all_stores = {}
cart_total = 1
cart = 'Items you\'ve purchased: '
stores_lst = {'freelancers':'', 'antiques':'', 'pet_shop':''}
for stores in (freelancers, antiques, pet_shop): all_stores.update(stores)
while cart_total <= 3:
    store = input(f'What store are you visiting?: {stores_lst.keys()}')
    if store == 'freelancers':
        item1 = input('What would you like from this store?: ' + str(sorted(freelancers)))
        all_stores.pop(item1)
        freelancers.pop(item1)
        cart = cart + " " + item1
        cart_total += 1
        del stores_lst['freelancers']
    elif store.lower() == 'antiques':
        item2 = input('What would you like from this store?: ' + str(sorted(antiques)))
        all_stores.pop(item2)
        antiques.pop(item2)
        cart = cart + " " + item2
        cart_total += 1
        del stores_lst['antiques']
    else:
        item3 = input('What would you like from this store?: ' + str(sorted(pet_shop)))
        all_stores.pop(item3)
        pet_shop.pop(item3)
        cart = cart + " " + item3
        cart_total += 1
        del stores_lst['pet_shop']
print(cart)
print(all_stores)
```

Comment: This question seems more fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but for a start I would look into handling wrong input. You can check if an item exists in a store, e.g. `if item in all_stores`, so you don't raise a KeyError when checking out an invalid item.

Comment: Two things jump out at once: You are nesting loops, and you have quite a bit of repeated code going on. I'd highly recommend looking into the "DRY" coding principle and looking at refactoring into functions.

Comment: New code I spent hours coming up with: """
#create an empty shopping cart
cart = {}
#loop through stores/dicts
for shop in (freelancers,antiques,pet_shop) :
    #inputbox  to show what you can buy...capture textstring of what was bought...make lowercase
    buy_item = input(f'Welcome to {shop["name"]}! what do you want to buy: {shop}').lower()
    #update the cart
    cart.update({buy_item:shop.pop(buy_item)}) # use pop...
    buy_items = ", ".join(list(cart.keys()))
print(f'You Purchased {buy_items}. Today it is all free. Have a nice day of mayhem!')
"""